# How to store a map's (eg: HashMap<Character, Integer>map) integer value into an int array[]?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Currently it is storing a single value to all indexes of the array and stores 
the last one at the end. 
I want to store all of the values of the map into an int array[].
I am tying something like:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
int values[] = new int[map.size()];

for(int v: map.values()){

    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        values[i] = v;              
                                    }
                        }
```

Comment: I suggest that the first thing you do is look carefully at the code you've got to understand why it's doing that. Hint: you won't want a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking to do is add every one of the `values` from the map a `values[]` in this case, `values` is `Integer`. To do this you should loop through the values in the map and add it to the array.

For this you can do something like this:

```
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    // fill map

    int[] valuesArray = new int[map.size()];
    int i = 0;

    for (int v : map.values()) {
        valuesArray[i] = v;
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `Set` of values of the `map` and turn it into an array with:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
//populate map
Integer[] values = (Integer[])map.values().toArray();
```